Using time clauses with different tenses

When she cooks dinner I will eat everything

Whn she has cooked dinner I will eat everything


Am I right that we need to use perfect to show that I eat once she finishes cooking and my 1 example without perfect would imply that I eat possible something different while she is in the process of cooking?

No, you're not right. I think this is yet another case of the choice of verb being irrelevant - what matters is the choice between when and while. Please remember that context (including contextually plausible meanings) is everything - the "concurrent" sense for #1 is so bizarre no-one would apply that interpretation unless it was explicitly forced by while.

But for instance. When I eat I use the napkin and when I have eaten I use the napkin present two different meanings?

"When she cooks dinner, I will eat everything" could mean "I really like her cooking (but don't care as much for someone else's). Whenever she is cooking, I eat  anything she makes."

"When I eat I use the napkin" is vague about time - it would be OK to say it if you only use the napkin to wipe your face after you've finished eating. "When I have..." in this context suggests after, but it can also be used for something that happened multiple times in the past: "When I have been to Italy, I have eaten pasta" probably means that each time you went to Italy, while you were there you ate pasta, but on other occasions you've not eaten pasta. You need to use common sense to interpret, or adverbs to clarify.

when + perfect does express the idea you want to express (when the cooking has been finished I will eat) but it is not the only way to express that idea, nor is it the most idiomatic.  Compare: I'll eat when she's done cooking.

"when she cooks dinner" is ambiguous. It could mean either repeated/habitual actions ("whenever she cooks dinner") or a specific action ("when she cooks dinner tonight"). You need more context to resolve this.

@Barmar: when can have several different meanings in such contexts. Including repeated and/or habitual actions, as you say. But it can also mean while AND after AND if (and never in something like when pigs fly).

@FumbleFingers Right, it has many uses. In "when pigs fly" it doesn't mean "never" by itself, the whole idiom has that meaning because pigs will never fly.

No, we don’t need to use any particular tense
The sense of words, including their tense, is context dependent.
The most natural implicit context here (divorced as it is from a wider context) is that you are going to eat the food that she has cooked. It is impossible to eat that food before it has been cooked so both “cooks” and “has cooked” take on the past tense, even though according to the dictionary, “cooks” is the 3rd person present form of “cook” and “has cooked” is the past perfect.
Other senses are possible, such as the hypothetical case that you will only eat everything when she cooks but not when anyone else does, or that you will eat at the same time as she is cooking, but these are less contextually obvious meanings. If that’s what you mean to communicate you need to be more explicit or give more context.
English is a Germanic language that was mugged by French and then kicked while it was on the ground by every American, African, Indian, Australian, and Asian language that walked by. It has concussion, so it can’t keep its tenses straight.
